# How can I find similar element name in XML by jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an XML file like

```
  <Name1> A </Name1>
  <Name2> B </Name2>
  <Name3> C </Name3>
  ...
```

Now, how can I find all the elements that have similar name by jQuery. For e.g. "LIKE" in SQL Server

```
Where something LIKE '% %'
```

I need to do like following in jQuery

```
if(elements in XML like 'Name%')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use something like this

```
var names = $(xml).find('*').filter(function() {
    return this.nodeName.match(/^Name[0-9]+$/i);
});
```

This will select all elements first and then it will filter all nodes that starts with `Name` and ends with a number.

[**Also check this example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TaKtq/1/)